# ListView control is not working

Tags: asp.net, listview

I see the video *[The ListView Control](http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-videos/video-225.aspx)*, but when I check [Visual Web Developer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_Web_Developer_Express) it does not show this control in Visual Web Developer.
When I run it I get:

> Unknown server tag 'asp:ListView'.

Answer (score -1):

Reset your toolbox toolbar in Visual Web Developer.

Comment: asking question and then answering and up-voting it?

Comment: no anirudha gupta & anirudha is a real-life-brother then anirudha gupta is a small brother & anirudha is a big brother his name are same everything is same in our brothers